# How to create XML editor for iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to create a XML editor (form view type) for iphone. Can anyone suggest me how to proceed in this regard. I know how to parse an XML document but I am having trouble in editing the contents of the file dynamically. This editor should be such that, a new node can be added or a node can be deleted, it can also edit the values.

Please help...

Comment: maybe accept some answers and stop writing words with z's and x's and someone might help

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? This sounds like "give me the codez"

Comment: No no not at all...I just want the way to proceed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you need to parse the document into a readable structure, finding a way to modify that structure, and write it back to XML.

Classes you are likely to need to write include `MyXMLDocument`, `MyXMLNode`, `MyXMLElement` and `MyXMLTextNode`, and `MyXMLNode` likely needs `NSArray *children;`, `MyXMLNode *parent;` and `MyXMLDocument *document;` as ivars.

You also probably need something akin to a `-stringValue` method; and an understanding of how the XML DOM usually works.